# Action Script3 error #1176

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

I wanna play a track per frame, i got this in the first frame called "Menu" I am new with as3 sound stuff, i have allready done all the game, is a question game based in plataform gaming using a mcPlayer without botons first i wanna play music in the menu diferent of music in all the game---

IF YOU COULD HELP ME WITH A WAY TO PLAY SOUND EFFECTS IN JUMPING AND BRICK HIT IT WOULD BE HELPFUL, maybe a guide or something

```
var mp3Menu:Sound= new Menu_mp3();
var Canal1: SoundChannel= new SoundChannel();
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, musicaMenu)
function musicaMenu (e:Event):void{
if(currentFrame=="Menu")
{
Canal1 = mp3Menu.play();
}
}
```

Comment: `Event.ENTER_FRAME` is for when Flash Player updates the display (animation movememnt etc) and is tied to the FPS in your **SWF settings**. So if your FPS is 100 then here you are saying "play sound 100 times every second". Try this as a starting point to fix your problem...  **(1)** Remove `function musicaMenu`. **(2)**  where you have code like `gotoAndStop("Menu")` add the line `Canal1 = mp3Menu.play();` and now the sound should play whenever you go to "Menu"..

Comment: My first frame is "Menu" but gee i will try making a new frame before "Menu" it should be the same thanks

Comment: I just made this in frame 1 "Menu"


    1`var mp3Menu:Sound= new Menu_mp3();`

     2`var Canal1: SoundChannel= new SoundChannel();`

     3`Canal1 = mp3Menu.play();`

Now im wondering how to stop it in the next frame

Comment: If you still need it... on next frame try this `Canal1.stop();`. I haven't put code in different frames for many years but it should be no problem (will be recognised from previous frame?). If any issues let me know and will suggest something...